# Used Reference in javascript is not available inside the catch-Block

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch, referenceerror

Inside our Javascript-Code we have a try...catch-block. The class works like the following:

> const ourCustomClassFile = require('./customFile');

Inside customFile.js we defined a function

```
const sendErrorNotification = (source, reason, scriptposition) => 
{ ...something and write a mail... 
}
```

our main-program got a try-catch block over the whole script like this:

```
const ourCustomClassFile = require('./customFile');
try{
   const inputFolder = this.config.folder.input;    
   const workFolder = this.config.folder.work;  
   const errorFolder = this.config.folder.error;
}catch(error){
   if (fs.existsSync(workFile)) {
               fs.renameSync(workFile, errorFile);
        }

   sendErrorNotification(
        file,
        `Errortext: ${error}`,
        actPosition
           );   
}
```

The function sendErrorNotification works fine inside the normal code of our main program, but inside the catch-block we get an Exception:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: sendErrorNotification is not defined

So I just Need to know: why is the function not defined?

Comment: use ourCustomClassFile.sendErrorNotification()

Comment: How is `sendErrorNotification` exposed for other consumers? Currently it's just a variable and how you reach it will depend on how (or *if*) you export it.

Comment: @VipulPatil If we use it like that, we get the message "TypeError: ourCustomClassFile.sendErrorNotificationis not a function"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inside your customFile.js

```
const sendErrorNotification = (source, reason, scriptposition) => { 
  ...something and write a mail... 
}
module.exports = {
  sendErrorNotification: sendErrorNotification
}
```

then, in your main.js file, call it like this:

```
const ourCustomClassFile = require('./customFile');
...
ourCustomClassFile.sendErrorNotification(..)
...
```